# duplicate weblogic domain from solaris 9 command line

Tags: sed, solaris, weblogic-10.x

I need to search for a string of characters in a weblogic domain and then replace that string with a new one. I tried doing a `grep -r` but `solaris 9` doesn't support it. I tried a find command:

```
find <mydir>-type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' {}+ .
```

This did not work.

I have multiple directory names, file names and file content to change.
I am essentially coping a weblogic domain, tar and zipping it, moving it, unzip, untar, rename and reconfig and then launch. all from command prompt.

ANY help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`-i` is a GNU sed extension.

Here is one way to achieve what you want with Solaris 9 commands :

```
find <mydir> -type f -exec ksh -c '
    for i do sed "s/string1/string2/g" $i > /tmp/foo && cat /tmp/foo > $i; done' ksh {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but i found my answer:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l <search string> {} \; | while read i; do perl -pi -e 's/<string1>/<string2>/g' $i;done
```

Thanks for the replies.